# Exception during aggregation of Object Type account on Application SalesforceTest

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, salesforce, sailpoint

The goal is to integrate Sailpoint Identity IIQ with Salesforce instance using a direct connector in Sailpoint.

I have successfully installed the following software on my laptop.

1. IGA - Sailpoint Identity IIQ version 8.3
2. Database - MySql version 8.0.35.0
3. Server - Apache Tomcat server version 9.0.83
4. Java JDK version 21 for Windows X64.

The connection has been established between Sailpoint and Salesforce using Basic authentication. When it comes to account aggregation, I am encountering the following error.
"
ERROR QuartzScheduler_Worker-2 sailpoint.api.Aggregator:1916 - Exception during aggregation of Object Type account on Application SalesforceTest. Reason: Unable to create iterator java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class connector.common.XmlUtil (in unnamed module @0x428aa84) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp to unnamed module @0x428aa84"

Could I please get inputs about this error and assistance in resolving the issue?

I am expecting the account aggregation between Sailpoint and Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

The supported versions of Java for IdentityIQ 8.3 are 8, 11 and 17. JDK 21 is not supported. There may be differences that the IdentityIQ code has not been updated for, yet.